# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m128i’ from type ‘int’

Tags: c, linux

*I have recently been doing some research on block cipher modes (encryption).
I was really interested in OCB (Offset codebook) and tried to implement it.
I used an implementation provided by the author of the algorithm. 
I am now receiving errors. The depth of these errors are a little too deep for me.*

The error listed below occurs a lot. I tried to read up on what _m128i is for,
but I have never really touched anything related to it. (Not that experienced on Linux)
I got the feeling that it may have something to do with the OS/compiler/settings?

The error:

**incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m128i’ from type ‘int’**

*(ran with gcc : gcc -march=native -O3 ocb.c timing_x86-1.c)*

Any insight would be really appreciated.

*EDIT*

Here is an example of where the error occurs. (the __m128i conversion)

```
static void AES_128_Key_Expansion(const unsigned char *userkey, void *key)
{
__m128i x0,x1,x2;
__m128i *kp = (__m128i *)key;
kp[0] = x0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)userkey);
x2 = _mm_setzero_si128();
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,1);   kp[1]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,2);   kp[2]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,4);   kp[3]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,8);   kp[4]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,16);  kp[5]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,32);  kp[6]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,64);  kp[7]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,128); kp[8]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,27);  kp[9]  = x0;
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,54);  kp[10] = x0;
}

#define EXPAND_ASSIST(v1,v2,v3,v4,shuff_const,aes_const)                    \
v2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(v4,aes_const);                           \
v3 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(v3),              \
                                     _mm_castsi128_ps(v1), 16));        \
v1 = _mm_xor_si128(v1,v3);                                              \
v3 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(v3),              \
                                     _mm_castsi128_ps(v1), 140));       \
v1 = _mm_xor_si128(v1,v3);                                              \
v2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v2,shuff_const);                                 \
v1 = _mm_xor_si128(v1,v2)

#define EXPAND192_STEP(idx,aes_const)                                       \
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x3,85,aes_const);                                \
x3 = _mm_xor_si128(x3,_mm_slli_si128 (x3, 4));                          \
x3 = _mm_xor_si128(x3,_mm_shuffle_epi32(x0, 255));                      \
kp[idx] = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(tmp),        \
                                          _mm_castsi128_ps(x0), 68));   \
kp[idx+1] = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(x0),       \
                                            _mm_castsi128_ps(x3), 78)); \
EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x3,85,(aes_const*2));                            \
x3 = _mm_xor_si128(x3,_mm_slli_si128 (x3, 4));                          \
x3 = _mm_xor_si128(x3,_mm_shuffle_epi32(x0, 255));                      \
kp[idx+2] = x0; tmp = x3
```

Comment: Post the piece of the code that is relevant to the problem maybe?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: all the EXPAND_ASSIST(x0,x1,x2,x0,255,1); lines throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot typecast into a machine register. That is what the load command is doing for you.

You just provide the pointer to the load command directly without a cast. It will copy from ram to the vector register. A cast cannot do that.

Comment: I am afraid I loaded the wrong piece of code. I changed it now. 
The error occurs on every single one of those EXPAND_ASSIST lines. (Your help is much appreciated!)

Comment: It's the same problem. You try to cast from `key` instead of loading `key`.

Comment: Where do you see a "typecast into a machine register"?

Comment: I removed the cast yet the error remains. The only mention of the __m128i type is in the declaration of (__m128i x0,x1,x2;) and (__m128i *kp = key;)

Comment: You need to read a book or other documentation. You cannot cast into machine register, being it explicitely or implicitely. Use the store command!